# Searching in input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, search

I'm having trouble searching. I have an array with customers, I want to search by name. Initially, everything works fine, but when I use backspace, the names do not update. Does not display the initial data from the array.

```
const[searchCustomer, setSearchCustomer] = useState('')
const changeSearchCustomer = (e) => {
    setSearchCustomer(e.target.value);
};

const searchingCustomer = (e) => {
  let customers = [...customers];
  customers = customers.filter((el) =>
  
    el.firstName
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(searchCustomer.toLowerCase())
  );

  setCustomers(customers)
}

<input type="text" placeholder="search..." value={searchCustomer} onChange={changeSearchCustomer} onKeyUp={searchingCustomer} />
```

Does not display the initial data from the array.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Perhaps show examples of 1.  I type xxxxx 2. I see yzysjs leading up to your "Does not display the initial data from the array." so it is clear what "initial data" means.  `customers` is not defined in your code which might actually help with your updated description and allow us to try to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `onKeyUp`? Put all the logic from `searchingCustomers` into the `onChange` handler instead. When you use `onKeyUp`, you will miss the ways that users can change the input without touching the keyboard (like autofill or copy & paste).

Also, you have some problems in `searchingCustomers`:

1. Assuming that your state value is named `customers`, you should not re-use that name where you assign `let customers = [... customers]`
2. Array.filter() already returns a shallow copy, so it is unnecessary to destructure and then filter the result. Just use filter.
3. It's bad practice to use `let` and then re-assign it by transforming the initial value. Use `const` and assign it the transformed value in the first place.

All together, this should be something like `const newCustomers = customers.filter(...); setCustomers(newCustomers)`.

Lastly, you are successively filtering the same list, which is leading to the problem you're having where the full list of customers doesn't come back after you clear the input.

You need to keep the full list of customers intact so that you can filter the full list when the input changes, instead of filtering a list that has already been filtered.
This means you need two lists, `allCustomers` which is never changed, and `filteredCustomers` which will change when your input changes.

Then your `onChange` will look something like this:
 `setFilteredCustomers(allCustomers.filter(...))`

Comment: Unfortunately, after the changes you suggested, the search still doesn't work completely correctly. It finds customers but after clearing the input it does not return the entire array. This has been the case so far.

Comment: Your problem probably lies in the fact that you're successively filtering the same list over and over again. You should have two lists, one holds all the customers, the other one holds the filter results.